# How does the blood of the veins in the legs get to the heart?

Tags: circulatory-system

Does it have something to do with the valves? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are expected to do some research on your own before posting here. That is the kind of question you ask google not here.

Comment: It has to do something with "muscle pump" and pressure in the right atrium. You can find out this from any decent explanation of the circulatory system...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The veins in your legs have one way valves. These prevent blood from flowing down, but do not actively push it up. However, normal muscle movement from walking etc will squeeze the veins to push blood through these valves, and so it will work its way up to where negative pressure in your heart atrium can begin having an effect. This does however mean that blood accumulates from long periods of standing without movement, and so exercises are needed to prevent fainting, for example, for soldiers on parade (see [Pathophysiology, Homeostasis and Nursing
By Roger Watson, Tonks N. Fawcett, Josephine N. Fawcett](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=c9jVSWDzS50C&lpg=PA57&ots=eea_PTjxVw&dq=soldiers%20on%20parade%20leg%20vein&pg=PA57#v=onepage&q=soldiers%20on%20parade%20leg%20vein&f=false))